# how to return a response from a Parse.com Cloud Code Module?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

From the parse.com example, in cloud/module.js I have

```
module.exports = {

...

search: function(params, options) {
  return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
    method: "GET",
    url: "https://externalapi.com"
  }).then(function(httpResponse) {
    console.log(httpResponse.text); //<--- THIS WORKS!
    if (options && options.success) {
      options.success(httpResponse);
    }
  }, function(httpResponse) {
    if (options && options.error) {
      options.error(httpResponse);
    }
  });
}
```

The code works, I can see the response console log in the parse code.

it says that `options` is undefined so it never call `options.success`

Then this, always returns empty

in cloud/main.js

```
Parse.Cloud.define("searchIt", function(request, response) {
  myModule.search({
        near: request.params.near,
        query: request.params.query
  }).then(function(httpResponse) {
    response.success(httpResponse);
  }, function(httpResponse) {
    response.error("Uh oh, something went wrong");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code to this:

```
  return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
    url: 'https://externalapi.com',
    success:function(httpResponse){

    },
    error:function(httpResponse){

    }
  });
}
```

and now is working